# "A novel" or "the novel" in various contexts

Tags: articles

Why should I use `the` in the first case and `a` in the second?

```
The novel is the most popular form of fiction.

A novel is a long narrative.
```

**My thoughts:**

For the **first case** I could think of the rule:

> Use THE with superlatives such as "the best", "the biggest", "the most
>   important", "the least interesting", etc.

So it's necessary to use a definite article because of  `the most popular`.

For the **second case** the relevant rule seems to be:

> Use A(AN) when you are talking about a thing in general, NOT a
>   specific thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've probably discovered, the simple rule is that the definite article *the* refers to one particular thing while the indefinite articles *a* and *an* refer to an unidentified thing.  Thus when we read

> The critic panned **the** novel

we know the critic didn't like one particular novel named in his review.  And for

> I picked up **a** novel at the library

you know that I checked out some novel, but you don't know which one.

Unfortunately, things aren't always that simple.  The definite article can mean the entire field of things under consideration, so for

> **The** novel is the most popular form of fiction

you're talking about novels as an art form.  The article doesn't have to associated with the superlative.  For instance

> The course will cover **the** novel from its beginnings in the early 18th century to the present.

The indefinite article may be used to refer to a representative singular to indicate the entire field as in your example

> **A** novel is a long narrative.

Here you're not talking about a single book (like the one I checked out of the library) but any novel, and by implication all novels.  In these uses, you may substitute the **plural** without changing the sense:

> **Novels** are the most popular form of fiction.
>   **Novels** are long narratives.

With the "simple usage first mentioned, this isn't so.  If I say

> I picked up **novels** at the library

I checked out more than one book.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply! Besides simple usage: `the` - novels as an art form, `a` -  representative singular to indicate the entire field. Does it mean that I may use either `a`, `the` or `plural` in both sentences? `plural` is possible for sure in both of them.

Comment: @Konstantin The simple answer is yes, but remember what happened with the last simple answer.  You have to take context into account.  If you've written a paragraph discussing *Anna Karenina* and then decide to make a general statement about ***the** novel* as an art form, your reader will likely be confused since *the* would seem to refer to the Tolstoy work.  Context is everything.